# Unable to get count rows to work for 1 hour timespan in given date range

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP and MySQL.

My DB structure is like so:

```
id, user, car, view_stamp
```

view_stamp is a TIMESTAMP like so: `2014-02-05 11:11:47`

What I want to do is get the '`user`' that has over 100 views in any given one hour span,  in the past 24 hours.

This is my failed attempt at a loop query:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(id) AS TotalViews 
FROM car_views 
WHERE TotalViews > 100 AND view_stamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
ORDER BY TotalViews DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

The above does not have the 'One hour Span' requirement, and I don't know how to include it. It sounds confusing I'm sure, So let me try and rephrase just in case I made no sense above...

The time to check is just the past 24 hours. Within that 24 hour span, I need to know if any user viewed more than 100 times in any given 1 hour span.

Thanks for any help. If I am missing any useful info, please let me know and I will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` to get per-user, per-hour totals. And you have to use `HAVING` to test aggregate data.

```
SELECT user, HOUR(view_stamp) AS the_hour, COUNT(*) AS hourly_views
FROM car_views
WHERE view_stamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY user, the_hour
HAVING hourly_views > 100
ORDER BY hourly_views DESC
LIMIT 10
```